# Adding value to input='range' causes graphical bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React ^16.9 and i am creating a input with `type='range'`, but when i add the starting value, `value="17"`, to the input i can no longer move the slider. it becomes fixed for some reason.

[image: current example]

**This works, but slider starts in the middle of the input range**

`<input className="range" type="range" min="0" max="100"/>`

**This doesnt allow me to move the slider**

`<input className="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="17"/>`

---

I cant seem to quite figure out what can could be causing this issue, any suggestions of why the GUI of the second slider does not move would be much appreciated.

Comment: As setting a default value and still being able to use the slider works in standard HTML, it must have to do with your implementation in react, so we need some more code to work with. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify a value you should also specify an onchange handler, so when you move the slider it updates the value.

Comment: Only if the slider value is bound to a reactive value, which we can only assume, but is not clear from what is provided in the question.

Comment: This actually solved it. I've been staring myself blind in code for to long i suppose. Thank you Mike.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the value into state and add onChange handler.

```js
// in constructor
const state = {
    sliderValue: 17
}

handleOnChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      sliderValue: e.target.value
    })
}

// in render
<input 
    className="range"
    type="range"
    min="0" 
    max="100" 
    value={this.state.sliderValue}
    onChange={this.handleOnChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(17);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        className="range"
        type="range"
        min="0"
        max="100"
        value={value}
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```